# Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\/reg": CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

After installing the Genymotion plugin for Eclipse and setting the directory to 
**"C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion"** , I'm still getting this error and my genymotion emulator won't start.

I'm running Eclipse Juno on Windows 8.1. What should I do ?

Comment: What happens exactly? Can you see the list of devices you have? Is there any message displayed? Can you launch the VMs through Genymotion software?

Comment: I'm getting "Error: Cannot run program “C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\/reg”: CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified". No Genymotion doesn't run and I can't see any VMs. I kinda gave up on the GenyMotion option because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Preferences > Genymobile > Genymotion and change the directory to the Genymotion installation directory. Might be this one on windows: 
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion